# Raster calculator error: Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, ndvi, multi-band

I'm attempting to create an NDVI raster using a multiband image from a Parrot Sequoia. It's got only 4 bands instead of 5 so I'm using the following setup for creating the NDVI .tiff:

[image: raster calculator example]

However, I get the following error message. This does not happen to me when I use the raster calculator for 5 band images like those produced by MicaSense RedEdge. I'm following the procedure written down [here](https://support.micasense.com/hc/en-us/articles/216290298-How-do-I-work-with-MicaSense-GeoTiff-s-in-QGIS-and-create-a-PDF-report-) on MicaSense's website.

Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset ndvi.tif: `ndvi.tif' does not exist in the file system, and is not recognized as a supported dataset name. Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider: gdal, URI: ndvi.tif

This are my layer's properties:
[image]

Comment: What did you put in the "Output layer" field? A full layer path is expected here.

Comment: I wrote "NDVI" . Other times I've done this the window let's me write down a name for the new layer that'll be created. I haven't had to choose an output layer.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while but it's really simple: The Sequoia Camera has 4 bands: blue green red and near infrared

So, in the raster calculator:

NDVI = (B5 - B4)/(B5 + B4)

Do not mistake the Sequoia for the RedEdge, which has 5 bands and provides data for calculating NDRE.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's no apparent problem with how you set up the band calculation - the error comes from the fact that when you specify an output like 'ndvi.tif' you're attempting to save it, so you need to specify a path.  You could create a temporary layer saved to memory (RAM) which would get loaded to your canvas after running Raster Calculator, but as you have it all you need to do is specify your ouput file in the upper right hand of the calculator window like:

```
C:\pathto\outputs\ndvi.tif
```